# Is it possible to get an answer of a method through model filter.values_list?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    var1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    var2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def method1(self, input1):
        -- do something based on input1, var1, var2 --
        return result
```

I want to define a filter on this model and I use this code:

```
objects = Foo.objects.filter(var1 = a)
for obj in objects:
    json = {'var1': obj.var1, 'var2': obj.var2, 'method': obj.method1() }
```

This code runs so slow, I think it try to load all db objects. How can I speed up this code.

Can I use filter(var1=a).values_list('var1', 'var2', 'method1') ?

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This is possible only if you can create SQL which will do same thing as your `method1`. And if yon can, than just use `annotate` on your queryset with this this SQL.

Comment: tnx for your comment, I already know your suggestion. I am looking for a more convenient way.

Comment: What do you actually do with the json? I highly doubt you need millions of objects, especially when you overwrite the json object every iteration

Comment: @Sayse , I want to send this data to ui and show it to user.

Comment: You want to show a user the data for millions of objects?... how are they supposed to comprehend all of it?

Comment: @Sayse, I filter over millions of data and result of filter is usually tens of data. But loading millions of data is very time consuming( Foo.objects )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I search for the answer, it is not possible to get methods through values_list.
To speed up this code, I must try to find which line and which methods are time consuming to run. Some packages such as '[python profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)' and '[Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar)' can be useful for this purpose.

Most of times, Queries to SQL are the most time consuming part of your codes. If times consuming part of your code is anythings else, maybe you must revised and restructured your code.